# Getting all possible labels via imap

Tags: java, imap, label

Using IMAP, how can I get all available labels from my gmail account. I need all my labels created using gmail to my ImapClient (using Java).

Answer (score 0):

FYI "*IMAP translates labels with a forward slash (/) into a folder hierarchy like you see in your computer's file system. If you have a label such as 'Family/Friends,' you may want to reconsider your naming schemes because your IMAP client will display it as a folder named 'Family' with a subfolder named 'Friends.'
To get labels using java, you can refer this code:
http://gmailassistant.sourceforge.net/src/org/freeshell/zs/gmailassistant/MailLabel.java.html